# Correlation between signalR and RTVS?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I am new to asp.net signal R and RTVS. My question is, are by any chance signal R and RTVS related in any way or are they totally different platforms used for different needs?

Comment: By RTVS, do you mean this: https://github.com/Microsoft/RTVS ? If so, then yes they are completely different. SignalR is a framework for notifications in web apps. RTVS looks like something to with the R programming language, which is a statistical programming language.

Comment: Yes R programming. Thought that the names may signify similar technology thing. Thanks for clearing it up Nick

Comment: SingnalR is in javascript (and maybe some other things)